# my jquery slider is running well but there is bug that it sometimes does'nt shows images on next or prev click

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Found solution for the playing and stopping the slider.But problem is now with my next and prev links .these links some times does not shows any image.** 
my code is on the 
http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh84/ftkLd/12/

```
var slides;
        var cnt;
        var amount;
        var i;
        var x;
        var timer;
        slides = jQuery('#my_slider').children();
        cnt = jQuery('#counter');
        amount = slides.length;
        i=amount;

 cnt.text(i+' / '+amount);
        function run_prev() {
          jQuery(slides[i]).fadeOut(1000);
            i--;

            if (i <= 0) i = amount;
            jQuery(slides[i]).fadeIn(1000);
            // updating counter
            cnt.text(i+' / '+amount);

        }
        x=0;
        function run_next() {
            // hiding previous image and showing next
            jQuery(slides[x]).fadeOut(1000);
            x++;
            if (x >= amount) x = 0;
            jQuery(slides[x]).fadeIn(1000);
            cnt.text(x+1+' / '+amount);

        }
        /***********start and stop functions***************/
        function run() {
        // hiding previous image and showing next
        jQuery(slides[x]).fadeOut(1000);
        x++;
        if (x >= amount) x = 0;
        jQuery(slides[x]).fadeIn(1000);
        timer = setTimeout(run,2000);
        }
        function MySlider() {
             timer = setTimeout(run,2000);
        }

        function stoper() {
              clearTimeout(timer);
        }

/***********end start and stop functions***************/


        function slide_show(){
            var timer;
                if(jQuery('#slide_show').html()=='Play Slideshow')
                {

                    jQuery('#slide_show').html('Stop Slideshow');
                     MySlider();
                }
                else
                { 
                   jQuery('#slide_show').html('Play Slideshow');
                   stoper()
                }
            }



// custom initialization

    jQuery('#prev2').on("click",run_prev);
    jQuery('#next2').on("click",run_next);
    jQuery('#slide_show').on("click",slide_show);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set  `timer`

You declare at the top:  `timer` but it is never filled.

So i think you should do:

```
timer =  setTimeout( run, inetrval );
```

Also take the function outside of Run()

```
function run() {
}

if ( inetrval > 0 ) {
    alert( inetrval );
    run();
    timer = SetTimeOut( run, inetrval )
}
```

Comment: thnx for your reply but i have tried that but no benefits...that comes undefined

Comment: @yogesh Added a new idea, try this.

Comment: i take out that how slider will not run independently because it is using recursion

Comment: @yogesh Oh yeah missed that one. I only think you should not be setting `timer` every time.